# How to get Google search results and exclude sub-pages?

Tags: google-search

Sorry if question title isn't clear. Let me explain with an example.

Search term: Blogging

Results I got from Google

1. https://www.bloggingbasics101.com/how-do-i-start-a-blog/
2. https://www.thebalancesmb.com › ... › Home Business › Home Business Toolbox
3. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blog
4. https://blogging.org/
5. https://shoutmeloud.com/
6. https://bloggingwizard.com/
7. https://bloggingarea.com/blogging-tips/

I want to remove 1,2,3 and 7. I am looking only the **home page (full domain)** as result. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little "script" that would remove such results from the results page. Note that it can keep the page empty, and you'll just need to pass to the next one.

**The best way to use it, in my opinion, would be a [bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet):**

```
for (var x of document.querySelectorAll('div.g h3.r a')) {
     if (!x.href.match(/https?:\/\/\w+?(?:\.\w+)+?\/$/)) {
        x.closest('div.g').remove();
     }
}
```

Just minify it and put it as a bookmarklet, and click it whenever you want to get only base domain results.

**A minified version done with [jscompress](https://jscompress.com/):**

```
for(var x of document.querySelectorAll('div.g h3.r a'))x.href.match(/https?:\/\/\w+?(?:\.\w+)+?\/$/)||x.closest('div.g').remove();
```

Comment: This works :-) closest() is a jQuery function? How it worked? As I know Google don't use jQuery

Comment: Without jQuery, just regular JS! [closest() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)